# How to get css class of model in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Please tell me that  how to get css class of model in angularjs? My example is given below.

Example:

```
ng-class="{'greenbtn' : fullname, 'redbtn':!fullname}"
```

Here I want to get whether fullname is redbtn or greenbtn from angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Try

HTML

```
ng-class="getDropdownClass(item)"
```

JS

```
   $scope.getDropdownClass = function (item) {
        try {
            if (item.fullname){
                return 'greenbtn';
            } else {
                return 'redbtn';
            }
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    };
```